# Android studio sync local database between multiple devices

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am creating a pos application on android.
The database for the app is in the cloud. That causes a problem when the internet is down. To solve that problem i have created a SQLite database that keeps needed information for the work of the people using the app. (the app sync's data with the cloud when possible).
But a new problem arises.
If a client wants to have multiple devices in his establishment, i need these devices to be synced. Meaning the SQLite databases on all the devices need to look the same.

I think i should be using WiFi direct as in WiFi p2p but after some research i am not so sure anymore. All the examples i have seen are file transfer oriented, but i need to transfer simple lists of classes.

This process should happen seamlessly once we set up the devices in the background threads.

Here is how i imagined it.
We have for example 3 devices.
All 3 devices need  to have all the SQLite data on them, and another important factor is that i have a fiscalID/orderID that needs to be incremented every time a order or fiscal is printed. 
So: We have a primary device, who handles the increment of the number, meaning when a secondary device wants to print a order/fiscal, he asks the main device for the id, once the secondary device gets the id, he inserts the order or fiscal, after that he sends the SQLite data entry to the main device, the main device spreads that data to all other secondary devices.

If WiFi direct is the only solution to this problem, can someone link me to a good tutorial on this topic? It seem's that tutorial's on this topic are scarce, which is a shame because WiFi direct/p2p seems like a interesting concept.

Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question but-  why not just fix the internet so it being down is really rare?  Synchronizing dbs is hard to do correctly.  Synchronizing them without a single source of truth (like a central server) is VERY hard.  You're looking at months or years of corner cases and bugs.  I'd just avoid doing it altogether.

Comment: fixing the internet is not a option. I am thinking of having a main device act as a central server. there must be way of doing this... the data that i have to sync is very basic.

Comment: There are ways, such as voting for a master/slave.  You can't just assume one of those devices is master, as you have to assume that device may not be reachable as well.  And this is ignoring the case of potential malicious actors (lets assume nobody is trying to insert a fake device to poison your data).  You're going to spend months getting it right, especially if you've never done it before and aren't familiar with the techniques.  I'd look at how difficult it would be to just do a delayed sync with the central server first.

Comment: I never found a good way to do this.